# How much is 2D geometry used in 3D?

Tags: 3d, geometry

I'm studying 2D geometry with eventual goal to study 3D geometry for building games - *very much looking forward to 3D!!*

Looking up on how to calculate hypotenuse of a right triangle in 3D I read that the the same 2D Pythagorean theorem can also be used in 3D right triangle to calculate the hypotenuse.

So now I'm curious on how much of the 2D geometry I'm learning right now will be reusable when I get to 3D?

By "**how much**" I mean

- Do devs throw away their 2D knowledge in 3D and use a whole new sets of formulas/theorems?
- Or almost all or at least 90% of 2D knowledge is reused in 3D?

Comment: Everything in 2D generally extends to 3D, and you do plenty of 2D projected stuff in games even when they ARE in 3D: collision-detection, lightmaps, animation, etc.

Comment: I understand that you'd like to know if you're wasting your time, but unfortunately, asking us to quantify how much is used will depend on the dev and the context and opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3D geometry is an extension of 2D geometry and a solid understanding of 2D geometry is useful in 3D development. Things can be more complex when shifting to 3D, but generally most things will remain familiar and can you can find the connections to their 2d counter parts. The Pythagorean theorem is a good example. In three dimensions, the distance between the points \$(x_1,y_1,z_1)\$ and \$(x_2,y_2,z_2)\$ is defined as:

$$d=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2 +(z_1-z_2)^2}$$

2D geometry is essentially 3D geometry restricted to a single Z plane. By restricted, we means all the z values must be fixed to some constant, \$c\$. And no matter what constant you choose, \$c-c=0\$, which means the distance formula simplifies as follows:

$$\begin{align}
d&=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2 +(z_1-z_2)^2}\\
d&=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2 +(c-c)^2}\\
d&=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2 +0^2}\\
d&=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2}
\end{align}
$$
At the end, we arrive at the 2D version of the Pythagorean theorem that you've already seen.

On the other hand, rotations are one of the things that is significantly more challenging when moving from 2D to 3D. Not only are 3D Euler rotations messier than 2D, because of the additional degree of freedom they're not even a particular good way to represent general rotation in 3D.

Occasionally, you can get some nice optimizations by realizing that a particular 3D problem can be reduced to its 2D counterpart. And while somewhat anecdotal, every 3D game programming book I recall starts off 2D geometry summary before moving into 3D geometry.   Most of your 2D geometry can be upcycled when moving to 3D.